# How do I access local C variable in arm inline assembly?

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly, keil

I want to access local variable declared in C in inline arm Assembly. How do I do that?

Global variables can be accessed like this,

```
int temp = 0;
Function(){
    __asm(
       ".global temp\n\t"           
        "LDR R2, =temp\n\t"                                                     
        "LDR R2, [R2, #0]\n\t"
    );
}
```

But how do I access local variables? I tried changing ".global" to ".local" for local variables, but it generated error (undefined reference to `temp').
The IDE I am using is KEIL.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Local variables either exist on the stack or in a register.  It will be difficult to transfer them without some sort of compiler support.  GCC inline assembler will put them in registers for you.  I think [Keil is based on GCC](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/compiler/6/).  `.local` just means a 'global' with static linkage.  If you declare `void foo(void) { static int bar;}` you can access bar this way.  However, that is not a normal concept of 'local' to a 'C' programmer.  It is a 'static'.

Answer (score 6):

According to GCC docs: [6.45.2.3 Output Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands)

You can pass the values like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int src = 1;
  int dst;   

  asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t add $1, %0" : "=r" (dst) : "r" (src));

  printf("0x%X\n", dst);

  return 0;
}
```

After your asm code you put the `':'` character and the values you want to pass like this: `"(=|+)(r|m)" (variable)`. Use `'='` when overriding the value and `'+'` when reading or overriding the value, then use the `'r'` letter if the value resides in a register or `'m'` if it resides in memory.

Comment: That's x86 with AT&T syntax (`add src, dst`), but yes, extended ASM with constraints is the right answer.  However, you should definitely not include the `mov` in your inline asm.  Always use constraints and let the compiler generate a `mov` if it wants to save the old value of `src`.  e.g. `asm("inc %0" : "=r"(dst) : "0" (src));` so `%0` starts as src and finishes as dst (matching constraint).  Of course you can't get optimal code for all cases this way; you're still preventing the compiler from emitting `lea 1(%rax), %esi` to copy-and-add.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Answer (score 3):

**`r` minimal runnable example**

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t in0 = 1, in1 = 2, out;
    __asm__ (
        "add %[out], %[in0], %[in1];"
        : [out] "=r" (out)
        : [in0] "r"  (in0),
          [in1] "r"  (in1)
    );
    assert(in0 == 1);
    assert(in1 == 2);
    assert(out == 3);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/812aa06db4ed0bba4f9965a3b4dfa7b8e7f6050f/v7/c/add.c).

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -std=c99 -ggdb3 -march=armv8-a -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -o main.out main.c
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -E LD_BIND_NOW=1 main.out
```

Disassembly:

```
gdb-multiarch -nh -batch -ex 'disassemble/rs main' add.out
```

Output excerpt:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
add.c:
6   int main(void) {
   0x0000000000000764 <+0>: fd 7b bd a9 stp x29, x30, [sp, #-48]!
   0x0000000000000768 <+4>: fd 03 00 91 mov x29, sp

7       uint64_t in0 = 1, in1 = 2, out;
   0x000000000000076c <+8>: 20 00 80 d2 mov x0, #0x1                    // #1
   0x0000000000000770 <+12>:    e0 0f 00 f9 str x0, [sp, #24]
   0x0000000000000774 <+16>:    40 00 80 d2 mov x0, #0x2                    // #2
   0x0000000000000778 <+20>:    e0 13 00 f9 str x0, [sp, #32]

8       __asm__ (
   0x000000000000077c <+24>:    e0 0f 40 f9 ldr x0, [sp, #24]
   0x0000000000000780 <+28>:    e1 13 40 f9 ldr x1, [sp, #32]
   0x0000000000000784 <+32>:    00 00 01 8b add x0, x0, x1
   0x0000000000000788 <+36>:    e0 17 00 f9 str x0, [sp, #40]

9           "add %[out], %[in0], %[in1];"
10          : [out] "=r" (out)
11          : [in0] "r"  (in0),
12            [in1] "r"  (in1)
13      );
```

So we see that `r` translated into stack `sp` relative `str` loads, which is where local variables live.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0, QEMU 2.12.

Comment: I don't think your `assert`s can truly test that `asm` didn't clobber input-only registers.  If you compile without optimization, the values will be reloaded from the stack.  If you compile *with* optimization, constant propagation will evaluate `in0 == 1` to true at compile time.  You'd need something like an `escape` function that used `asm("" : "+r"(in0));` to make the compiler lose any knowledge about the *value* of the var while keeping it in a reg, before the `assert`.